# how to select two levels of hierarchy of the html?

Tags: jquery

Suppose, this html...

```
<div id="main">
  <div><!--should select this-->
    <article>should not select this</article>
  </div>
  <div><!--should not select this-->
    <article>should select this</article>
    <article>should select this</article>
  </div>
</div>
```

To re-declare my question: I want to select article's one level up parent if article is only one and if article is more than one it's one level up parent should not be selected but instead article itself should be selected.

I need the cleaner way to select this as the selector.

Comment: in the second case, which article should be selected? The article itself or its sibling?

Comment: the article itself that is both articles in my example and inside article's div shouldn't be selected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
var $els = $('#main').find('> div, > div > article').filter(function () {
    return this.tagName == 'DIV' ? $(this).children().length == 1 : $(this).siblings().length > 0
});

console.log($els.get())
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/vZ35e/)

Answer (score -2):

```
$('article').filter(function () {
    return $(this).siblings().length===0 ? true : false;
});

// Or in each-syntax:
$('article').each(function(){
    var $siblings = $(this).siblings(); // select (possible) siblings
    if( $siblings .length ===0 ){ // of none found
        $elem = $(this).parent(); // select parent
    }
    else{
        $elem = $siblings; // otherwise get the siblings
    }
});
```

This example uses a filter or each, but you can replace this with a `.map()` function, I've done this way to give a demo how it could work

For those we care: I've tested the siblings result, if you have 3 articles, and test 1 of them how many siblings they got, it says 2. It excludes itself.

*edit: Misunderstood, updated answer, please review downvotes :)*